# Pattern for untangling nested if/else structure with asynchronous calls

Tags: java, android, oop, design-patterns, asynchronous

I have to work out a result which depends on many models obtained from asynchronous calls. Those asynchronous calls performs network calls or UI interruptions (prompts for the user requiring him/her to choose something).

My first attempt has been just to invoke, recursively, to an ugly if/else nest, that looks like this:

```
public void getResult() {
    if(mModelA == null) {
        getModelA();
    } else if(mModelB == null) {
        getModelB(mModelA.someData);
    } else if(mModelB.value == -1) {
        askUserAboutValue();
    } else if(mModelB.value == 5) {
        getModelC();
    } else if(mModelB.value == 3) {
        getModelD();
    } else if(...) {
        ....
    }
}
```

The methods getModelX and askUserAboutValue perform asynchronous tasks and when they finish, they write some global variable and call getResult() in its callback.

I wonder if there is a pattern that could simplify this spaghetti code and what is more, to simplyfy its unit testing.

I think that isolating every check in simpler methods (like: checkModelA()) could help, but it might exist something better.

By the way, this is executed in the Activity of an Android application, so I'm constrained to have all this code in only one class.

Comment: Are you waiting for all the asynchronous calls to complete before executing getResult()?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a switch would work better for this? Or just use a custom method that takes the Integer returned by mModelB.value? Notice the "Integer" not int to check for that null.

Another suggestion would be to use polymorphism, maybe create a method called "getModel(mModelB.value)".

Answer (score 0):

Switch Case / If-Else problems are generally solution for bad design situation.

It looks like you should SubClass your ModelB so that Value of 5, -1 and 3 are different ChildClass which all relates to a Parent Class which would be a ModelB.

But from the function called in every If clause, it seems like -1 is not a SubClass but an error. It feels like in one single function you try to identify the right class that should be use and manage 1 case of error. Error case should be treated inside of the function called.

So in resume, this is a mess? I would gladly help you more but you will have to give me more info on what are those "value" and those "model" and how they interact with each other or their use so that I can try and come up with a better design. Your problem does not sit only on this If/Else function, it's bigger.